# Print an array of char, but the ending is not expected

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, printf

I don't understand why there are random char after `abc`. what is the reason? How to print out only `abc`? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[3];   
    char(*ptr)[3]; // declare a pointer to an array

    arr[0] = 'a';
    arr[1] = 'b';
    arr[2] = 'c'; 

    ptr = &arr; 
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    //printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The array is not 0-terminated.

Comment: In C all strings need to be *null-terminated*.

Comment: Also note that the `%s` format for `printf` expects the argument not only to be a null-terminated string, it must also be of the type `char *`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. That means you can't use `ptr` as argument to a `%s` format in `printf`.

Comment: That is not true, you can pass any pointer. Better check how does the va_list works, and how does compiler treats pointers ;)

Comment: @KolkilKolk: Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8, the argument corresponding to an `s` conversion specifier “shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.” That is, it must be a `char *`, `unsigned char *`, or `signed char *`. Per 7.21.6.1 9, “If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.” Per 6.7.6.2 2, for pointer types to be compatible, they must point to compatible types. None of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` are compatible with `char [4]`.

Comment: @KolkilKolk: The behavior of `va_list ` is irrelevant because `printf` is specified by 7.21.6, without reference to how `va_list` works. As for how the compiler treats pointers, you may be familiar with compilers that use one format for all pointers, but this is not required by the C standard and is not true in all compilers. A C implementation may have different formats for different kinds of pointers, such as one format for pointers to `char` and others that may have sub-word alignment, a different format for pointers to `int`, and/or a different format for large objects.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thank for mentioning the pointer to array thing, you answered the question I would wanted to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string need to be terminated with a `\0`. Make sure to allocate enough space to store the terminator as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[4];   
    char(*ptr)[4]; // declare a pointer to an array

    arr[0] = 'a';
    arr[1] = 'b';
    arr[2] = 'c'; 
    arr[3] = '\0'; // <-- terminator

    ptr = &arr; 
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    //printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `char arr[4]` you will have random content in your array. If instead you would use

```
char arr[4] = "abc";
```

This will lead to

```
char arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

See how the other places are filled with a `0` so you don't have to set it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The reason of the random characters is that you are trying to output the array as a string using the conversion specifier `%s`.

But the character array `arr` does not contain a string (a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`).

So to output it using the function `printf` you can do for example the following way:

```
printf( "%*.*s\n", 3, 3, arr );
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 4 Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %.
>   After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — An optional precision that gives ...  the maximum number of bytes to
>   be written for s conversions.

Answer (score 0):

String must be terminated with `0` .
So you have to declare 4 element array.

```
char arr[4] = "abc";
```

The `strlen` function wich all *printf* function family uses, reads string till `0` value is found.
So `strlen` returned length of memory block that starts at your array beginning and ends with first zero.
This can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `printf` must detect the end of strings it processes by recognizing the terminating null character, but that does not mean it uses `strlen`.

Comment: Well that is implementation dependent. Glibc printf uses.

Comment: Since it is implementation dependent, we may expect it is not true that “all printf function family uses”. Certainly it is irrelevant to explaining the specified behavior of `printf`. Yes, the behavior of `printf` when passed, for `%s`, an array that is not null-terminated within its bounds is not defined by the C standard, and your answer should state that, but bringing up `strlen` is just irrelevant.

Comment: You are right I should mention that I am talking about the glibc.